# org mode: Numbered subtree whose parent has UNNUMBERED: t

Tags: org-mode, org-export

As of version 8.3 of org, numbering of subtrees in export [can be toggled](http://orgmode.org/Changes.html) via the `:UNNUMBERED` property.  This applies to subheadings *regardless of their own* `:UNNUMBERED` property value.  MWE:

```
* Heading
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: t
:END:
** Subheading
:PROPERTIES:
:UNNUMBERED: nil
:END:
```

This generates for LaTeX export

```
...
\section*{Heading}
\label{sec:orgheadline2}
\subsection*{Subheading}
\label{sec:orgheadline1}
```

Is there some other way to toggle this at the subheading level?  I need a heading to be un-numbered when exported to LaTeX, but its child subheading to be numbered.  I.e. `\section*{Heading}` and `\subsection{Subheading}`.